# How to make a JavaScript ajax asynch call appear to be synchronous?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I'm using the Dhtmlx UI library.  In their grid component you can check for input on the fly using an 'OnEdit' method.  The method provides the following params : rowid, colid, newval, oldval.

Most of the time I am fine using the OnEdit method to validate or INVALIDATE info being entered depending on which col is being called and the newval and oldval info.  So usually my OnEdit method would look something like this:

```
function OnEdit(rowid,colid,newval,oldval)
{
  if first test fails return false;

  if second test fails return false;

  etc.

  return true;
}
```

Returning false resets the field value to oldval.

However for one particular case I need to go back to the server and check on a value.  If the value is different that I hold locally then I need to return false.  So my revised method looks like this:

```
function OnEdit(rowid,colid,newval,oldval)
{
  if first test fails return false;

  if second test fails return false;

  //third test  
  Fetch data from server via async ajax and if different to currval then 
  return false.

  ......
  if nth test fails return false;

  etc.

  return true;
}
```

Of course by the time the third test executes and completes the system has reached the end of the tests and returns true.

I need to know how I should be setting up the third test so that the system waits for the result before continuing to the 'nth test' case.

Comment: That isn't really possible. You can sorta make it "look" sync by using async/await, but you still won't be returning true or false from OnEdit, it will instead return a pending promise.

Comment: You'd have to return a tentative `true`, then potentially change the grid cell in the ajax success callback.

Comment: Should you not separate the tests though? `However for one particular case I need to go back to the server and check on a value.` personally, I would mock this service response and check just the service on it's own in a separate test

Comment: I'm liking Chris G's suggestion.  The async call is fast enough for the user to not notice that a 'true' was sent before being re-set to the 'oldval' in the call back.  Thanks I'll give that a try.

Comment: Just to confirm that Chris G's suggestion worked well.  Its a pity that the synchronous ajax call was deprecated on the grounds that it made for a bad user experience.....but surely that is a matter between the programmer and their clients, not for a standards authority.  But that's for another soap box. LOL.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to set async: false in ajax option.That will wait until receive response
from server.

Comment: Sync ajax calls are deprecated.